# Sellix not replacing custom field variables in the redirect URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect, shopify

I am using Sellix to sell my products and I have set up custom fields to collect additional information from my customers during the purchase process. I am trying to use these custom field values in the redirect URL after a purchase.

According to the Sellix documentation, I should be able to use any field from the invoice object in the redirect URL. I have tried to use the custom field variables like this:

```
https://faucet.lol/purchased?Domain={{custom_fields.Domain}}&Subdomain={{custom_fields.Subdomain}}
```

However, this just ends up redirecting to `https://faucet.lol/purchased?Domain=&Subdomain=`, meaning the custom field values are not being replaced in the URL.

I have confirmed that the custom fields "Domain" and "Subdomain" are correctly set up in the product details and are being populated during the purchase process.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a solution or workaround?

Comment: Please provide the URL to that specific part of the documentation you are talking about.